# beyond basics with rx in python

Tags: python, yaml

Started using [this](http://rx.codesimply.com/) fantastic Rx library for validating a YAML file against a schema.

Just wondered, if I can use it for more advanced stuff like:

1. if a given string value is in a known range. example: value color must be either red/blue/green
2. can I use regex with it? Example: known file formats are either .txt or .log, so I want to validate any file with these formats - *.txt / *.log
3. How can I represent a tuple of 2 ints in YAML scheme?
4. How can I add validation to the keys of map type? for example that the keys are strings, and the key "must_be" must be in it?

Comment: Have you tried to ask on the mailing list?

Comment: No, can you refer me to it

Comment: https://www.listbox.com/subscribe/?list_id=137345 it is mentioned at the bottom of the page you refer to.

Comment: Sent a message. If I get an answer I'll publish it here

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have solved two of these on your own.  On the other two:

> can I use regex with it? Example: known file formats are either .txt or .log, so I want to validate any file with these formats - *.txt / *.log

No.  Regex are not sufficiently cross-platform.  I wrote a Perl-only plugin for PCRE, here: https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Rx-Type-PCRE

It should be easy to write a compatible PCRE plugin for any language using PCRE.  Alternately, if you're only using one language, you can just write a plugin in that language for whatever you need like /my/string-ending-with `{substr:".txt"}` etc.

> How can I represent a tuple of 2 ints in YAML scheme?

You have a few options.  I would write:

`type: //seq
contents:
- type: //int
- type: //int`

Another option:

`type: //arr
contents: //int
length:
  min: 2
  max: 2`

Answer (score 1):

Solved questions number 1 and 4:

question 1 - Let's assume that color parameter is under a required scope in //rec type:

```
color: {type: //any, of: [
                          {type: //str, value: red},
                          {type: //str, value: green},
                          {type: //str, value: blue}
        ]}
```

question 4:

if your keys are strings, you can use //rec type to indicate must and optional keys and which key names you are supporting:

```
some_map: {type: //rec,
required: 
must_have_key1: type: //str,
must_have_key2: type: //str}
```